# Binning a set into subsets deterministically

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics

I have an unordered set of `n` unique, positive integers. I want to partition it into `ceil(n / k)` unordered sets of up to `k` numbers (`k << n`) in a deterministic way (I want to get a sequence of the same `ceil(n / k)` output sets without depending on a fixed order of the input).

Is there a way to do so that has superior algorithmic complexity to sorting the set and partitioning the resulting sequence?

Comment: (Repeated [quickselect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)?)

Comment: The question is not clear. Please elaborate on this statement: "I want to get a sequence of the same ceil(n / k) output sets without depending on a fixed order of the input". Perhaps, an example will work.